# What operating systems will "\n" create a new line in? (Java)

Tags: java, strings, formatting

(Java Version 8 Update 60)

Hello. I am currently writing a program for my first Java assignment in college.

My question is, in what operating systems will

`System.out.println("Hello,\n World");`

result in

```
Hello,
World
```

to be written in the console?

I am writing a program that extensively uses \n to format my strings and this is working 100% fine on my laptop (Windows 10). I am just afraid that this will result in some wacky things such as

`Hello,\n World`

on other operating systems. My instructors use Mac and Linux and possibly older versions of Windows.

Edit: I've also seen something about "\r\n" somewhere, can anyone explain this as well?

Comment: If you're using Java, *any operating system capable of running Java.*   That's kinda the whole point. `\r` is [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), `\n` is [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).  Some of you young'uns have never seen a [teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter); in the old days it took two [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) to [move a print head to the beginning of the next line](http://micah.cowan.name/projects/term-talk/checkout/images/crlf.gif).

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)**

Comment: You may have an issue on some systems since the newline may be \r\n and not only \n, but probably not.  If you want to be sure, you can use java environment property `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get the correct usage everytime in your program.

Comment: It's nicer to use `%n` as the platform independent new line. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html and this stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character This makes usage equally concise as using `\n` and you avoid unnecessary string concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already indicated, your question requesting a list is likely to get closed. You may be able to save it from being closed by rewording it to not ask for a list.  So, I will give you an answer which does not include a list.

Generally,

```
 System.out.println("Hello,\n World");
```

will always result in

```
Hello,
World
```

in the console of any operating system out there.  In Linux and other systems belonging to the general Unix family, it is a given fact that this will work, because "\n" is the linefeed in these systems.

However, in Windows, where the linefeed character is "\r\n", emitting "\n" will still work.  So obviously, Java goes through the trouble of providing some kind of conversion.  However, I have never come across any official promise on behalf of Java that this conversion will always be provided.

If you are really concerned about this issue and do not want to leave anything to chance, then you should not emit "\n", you should emit the string obtained from the following call:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```